# Live chart in Highcharts makes the line series very .. mountainous

Tags: highcharts

I have a very simple line chart which initially looks correct. See [image: BeforeAddingPoints.png].

But after adding points (see [image: AfterAddingPoints.png]) to it, it suddenly draws mountains instead of a line. (Sorry I cant come up with a better word for mountains)

In AfterAddingPoints.png, the points are correctly rendered but instead of drawing a line from point A to point B, it draw a line from point A to some point C (creating a mountain) and then to point B.

FYI: I cannot share code but what could made adding points make the lines go crazy?

Im using Highcharts v6.0.1

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a weird behaviour, are you sure that there is no point between A and B (the mentioned C)? Are you able to reproduce this issue on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: There is no point C. I know because I debugged the data array in console and also if there was a point, I could hover over it. I think it has to do with the data that is being generated by my appp. Im going to completely strip down the chart, create an array manually and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for this. This was happening because the live data points I was appending had millis (my X-axis. See images from OP) in past.
In short: when a chart *initially* shows data from A to B....with live charts, you cannot insert a point C where C is between A and B. This is expected behavior and it was my millis calculations that were wrong.